# textbox/richtextbox cursor moves to position zero

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm trying to code a alphanumeric mobile phone like keyboard(keypad). So, i put letters in textbox, but everytime i press the one of my buttons, textbox cursor moves position zero and writing form there.

i'm try the selection changed event but not worked because textbox's itself changes to zero, my selection_changed code handles from there.

I need to not to changed cursor position to zero by default.

heres my form looks like.

[image]

MyCode for one button:

```
private void button3_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MyTimer.Start();

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        clicked += e.Clicks;
    }

    switch (clicked % 2)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            if (clicked > 1)
            {
                if (selectionstart < textBox1.Text.Length)
                {
                    string myString = textBox1.Text.ToString();

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    string part1 = myString.Substring(0, selectionstart);

                    int length = myString.Length - selectionstart - 1;
                    string part2 = myString.Substring(selectionstart + 1, length);
                    sb.Append(part1);
                    sb.Append("a");
                    sb.Append(part2);
                    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    string myString = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                    myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - 1);
                    textBox1.Text = myString;
                    textBox1.AppendText("a");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (selectionstart < textBox1.Text.Length)
                {
                    string myString = textBox1.Text.ToString();

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    string part1 = myString.Substring(0, selectionstart);

                    int length = myString.Length - selectionstart;
                    string part2 = myString.Substring(selectionstart, length);
                    sb.Append(part1);
                    sb.Append("a");
                    sb.Append(part2);
                    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    string myString = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                    myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - 1);
                    textBox1.Text = myString;
                    textBox1.AppendText("a");
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        case 0:
        {
            if (clicked > 1)
            {
                if (selectionstart < textBox1.Text.Length)
                {
                    string myString = textBox1.Text.ToString();

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    string part1 = myString.Substring(0, selectionstart);

                    int length = myString.Length - selectionstart - 1;
                    string part2 = myString.Substring(selectionstart + 1, length);
                    sb.Append(part1);
                    sb.Append("b");
                    sb.Append(part2);
                    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    string myString = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                    myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - 1);
                    textBox1.Text = myString;
                    textBox1.AppendText("b");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (selectionstart < textBox1.Text.Length)
                {
                    string myString = textBox1.Text.ToString();

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    string part1 = myString.Substring(0, selectionstart);

                    int length = myString.Length - selectionstart;
                    string part2 = myString.Substring(selectionstart, length);
                    sb.Append(part1);
                    sb.Append("b");
                    sb.Append(part2);
                    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    string myString = textBox1.Text.ToString();
                    myString = myString.    Substring(0, myString.Length - 1);
                    textBox1.Text = myString;
                    textBox1.AppendText("b");
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you change the value of the textbox? Can you show the code when you click a button?

Comment: You have a serious case of code duplication here! Where do you get selectionstart from?

Comment: i solved the problem. i have handled with textbox enter and textbox leave signals. thanks to @o_weisman i remove the duplicates. `code private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.SelectionStart = selectionstart;
        }

        private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selectionstart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        }
`